# How to make a dynamic list based on MULTIPLE criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I want to make a dynamic list based on multiple criteria . I've copied and changed to my needs this formula  :

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$26,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$26="Stire",ROW($B$2:$B$26)),ROW(2:2))-1,1),””).
```

it works but since I need multiple criteria I've tried to change it but I get the #NAME? error :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$26,SMALL(IF(($C$2:$C$26="Stire")*($E$2:$E$26>=TIME(19,0,0))*($F$2:$F$26<=TIME(20,0,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$26)),ROW(2:2))-1,1),””)
```

I've tried the IF statement alone to see if it works and it did :

```
=IF(($C$2:$C$26="Stire")*($E$2:$E$26>TIME(19,0,0))*($F$2:$F$26<=TIME(20,0,0)),$B$2:$B$26)
```

I also tried doing this via AND but I get the same error .

I use EXCEL 2016.

Comment: It's pretty hard to figure out your data from a formula that does not work. Please learn [ask], then edit your question and post a data sample. Explain what you want to achieve. Then post a comment to alert people following this question.

Comment: for starters, your if statement is not the same as the second formula `($E$2:$E$26>TIME(19,0,0))` maybe check your spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try nesting the IF tests instead of using the *

`IF($C$2:$C$26="Stire", IF($E$2:$E$26>TIME(19,0,0), IF($F$2:$F$26<=TIME(20,0,0),$B$2:$B$26)),"")`

Comment: Hey , that does work :  ```=INDEX($B$2:$B$26,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$26="Stire",IF($E$2:$E$26>=TIME(19,0,0),IF($F$2:$F$26<=TIME(20,0,0),ROW($B$2:$B$26)))),ROW(2:2))-1,1)``` . but now there is another issue the first item that would fit all IFs is omitted and isn't shown . Can you help me with that ?

Comment: can you show you're actual data layout by row and column? that would help with solving any errors.